# zero-length regex: go to beginning of indentend line

Tags: regex

Sorry for asking just another regex question. But, in my defense, I (a) searched the site, and (b) tried to solve it myself for a while first. However I'm stuck because I'm trying to get zero-length match, which I find tricky to understand.

Okay, so here the behavior I'm trying to find a regex for: "go to" (i.e. a zero-length match) right before the first non-space character after the beginning of line, in case there is one, otherwise: ^

Going by cases:

- empty line --> position before first character of line, ^
- line starting immediately with non-space character --> ^ again
- line starting with any number of spaces followed by (any number of) non-space --> position before the first non-space

---

re: which language exactly? I'm using regex inside TextMate. According to the documentation:

> TextMate uses the Oniguruma regular expression library by K. Kosako.
>
> The following is taken from http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt.
>
> Oniguruma Regular Expressions Version 5.6.0    2007/04/03

re: what am I trying to achieve?

In any given line, which might be empty or not, I want to either (1) be in the position at the beginning of the line, if either (1.1) the line is empty, or (1.2) the line begins with a non-space character, or (2) be in the position before the first non-space character.

I'll try to give a better example. On top, the input string, and below the number telling the position in the line where I'd like to end up. 's' being a single space character, 'n' a single non-space character, 0 being the position 'start of string'.

```
[empty line]
0

n
0

nsn
0

sn
1

ssn
2
```

Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Can you describe it in greater detail, perhaps a bigger example?

Comment: What language do you use? What are you trying to achieve? "empty line --> position before first character of line": there isn't a "first character of line", th e line is empty! "position before the first non-space": position at the last space? Show example strings.

Comment: @neoneye Added another example, hope it's better now.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Right. Sorry for the sloppy phrasing. Added a better example (I hope), and which language.

Comment: A regex doesn't "go to" anywhere: it matches (or not) strings. You can match the start of a line with additional possible white space characters: `^\s*` (this assumes the regex is greedy, which is normally the case). 
Where that puts your cursor, depends on the logic behind the cursor movement (does it move to the end of a regex, or the start?)

Comment: @Evert "A regex doesn't 'go to' anywhere": that's why I phrased my question title the way I did. I'm looking for a zero length match that behaves as if it is "going to" a position. `^\s*` matches the white space as well which is what I was hoping to avoid. I'll simply ask: is what I was trying to do impossible (hack or not)? There's no way to have a zero length match at another position than the predefined anchors?

Comment: Your third point doesn't consitute a zero-length match: you'll want to match your leading white space.

Comment: What you apparently *do* want, is to position your cursor *at the end* of the matching regex. The regex doesn't have to be zero length for that. But again, the positioning part is another step, which depends on what TextMate is doing (apparently, it positions things at the start of the matching regex); perhaps there is an option to let TextMate position your cursor at the end of a matching regex.

Comment: A look ahead or look behind assertion could help you, except that it doesn't allow for variable-sized matches.

Comment: @Evert Good point, I didn't notice that not all of my cases are zero length matches. I didn't find a way to tell TextMate something like 'place cursor at end of match'. But I could rephrase the task as follows (correct me please if I'm wrong): Starting from EOL, find any combination of white spaces and non-white spaces up to: beginning of line followed by an arbitrary number of white spaces. Does that make sense? If so, if I'd go to the beginning of /that/ match, I'd end up where I want to be, right?

Comment: Possibly, though I think you still might run into a look-behind assertion with a variable-sized match. Perhaps `\S.+$` could work for a line with non-whitespace, since regexes are normally greedy (assuming your regex works on lines, and not across lines).